# How to create a horizontal bar graph about reviews on each product?

Tags: drupal

I am trying to create a horizontal bar graph showing how many 1star, 2star etc reviews there are on each product, just [like Amazon does](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0307590615).

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any contributed modules that I know of that do just what you're looking for. With a lot of work, you might be able to accomplish it with a combination of the [Fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar), [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), and [Views Charts](http://drupal.org/project/views_charts) modules. There's a good chance it's going to require some custom development though.